# "Name (1)" challenge in custom files

Tags: c#, string

So, before I describe my problem you need some context:
I have some custom file that describe some objects by text. One of the lines of this file looks like this:

```
...
~
InWalls:
[0](Name = "Wall", Pos = 1|2, Rot = 7)
~
...
```

my program reads this file like so

1. join all lines in file
2. delete all spaces
3. split line by "~"
4. for(each line)

   4.1 split by ":"

   4.2 swith on first (in this case it's "InWalls")

   4.3 find in second "(", ")" and substring between (we get "Name = "Wall", Pos = 1|2, Rot = 7")

   4.4 split by ","

   4.5 each split by "="

   4... do staff and so on..

Really simple concept, isn't? Basically, as you understand, I use `String.Split()` and `String.SubString()` a lot, and everything working.. BUT!! What if my string looks like this..

```
...
~
InWalls:
[0](Name = "Wall (1)", Pos = 1|2, Rot = 7)
~
...
```

here on step 4.3 I will get not "Name = "Wall (1)", Pos = 1|2, Rot = 7", BUT "Name = "Wall (1", and I don't know how to fix this.. I need property "Name", and I can't just cut off this part... Does some has any thoughts on that?

Comment: We need actual code, input/output examples.  Please include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: Escape the strings before writing them, de-escape after reading.  For example %28 = ( , %29  = ) and %% for %.

Comment: Things that have matching "opening" and "closing" "delimiters" need a **stack** to "parse" properly. [Distantly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). [Beginning study material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Comment: How sold are you on that syntax? Why not use a similar standard syntax like JSON that already has parsers written?